# Inherit from **another** class other than actual parent class

Tags: ruby, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, superclass

I've been doing some 'monkey-patching' (ahem excuse me superman-patching), like so, adding the below code and more to file(s) in my `"#{Rails.root}/initializers/"` folder:

```
module RGeo
 module Geographic
 class ProjectedPointImpl
  def to_s
    coords = self.as_text.split("(").last.split(")").first.split(" ")
    "#{coords.last}, #{coords.first}"
  end# of to_s
  def google_link
    url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=#{self.to_s}"
  end
 end# of ProjectedPointImpl class
end# of Geographic module
end
```

I ended up realizing that there were two different `_Point_` instances which I wanted to utilize these methods on (both were strings with the same formatting, i.e. Well-Known Text (WKT)), and added an exact copy of the above two methods to a certain `RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl` class space.

I then, in my youthful, unexperienced way, after thinking about DRY (don't repeat yourself) principles, proceeded to create an *ad hoc* class which I presumed I might be able to inherit from for both

```
class Arghhh
  def to_s
    coords = self.as_text.split("(").last.split(")").first.split(" ")
      "#{coords.last}, #{coords.first}"
  end# of to_s

  def google_link
    url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=#{self.to_s}"
  end
end
```

and told my classes to inherit from  it i.e.: `ProjectedPointImpl < Arghhh`

I was promptly responded to by ruby with this error when I stopped and then tried to reload my rails console:

```
`<module:Geos>': superclass mismatch for class CAPIPointImpl (TypeError)
```

...

I think my naivete in trying to get CAPIPointImpl (in this case) to inherit from *another* class than its parent *also* highlights my knowledge gap on this subject very explicitly

What methods might I be able to use to practically graft extra shared methods onto two classes coming from otherwise separate parents? Does ruby allow for these types of abstract exceptions?

Comment: Ruby does not support multiple inheritance.  If you try to reopen an already defined class with inheritance but with a different parent, so then you get the error you posted.  Go read about modules, and see what Richard Cook says below and you should be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to define the new methods in a module which you then "mix into" the existing classes. Here's a rough sketch:

```
# Existing definition of X
class X
  def test
    puts 'X.test'
  end
end

# Existing definition of Y
class Y
  def test
    puts 'Y.test'
  end
end

module Mixin
  def foo
    puts "#{self.class.name}.foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "#{self.class.name}.bar"
  end
end

# Reopen X and include Mixin module
class X
  include Mixin
end

# Reopen Y and include Mixin module
class Y
  include Mixin
end

x = X.new
x.test # => 'X.test'
x.foo  # => 'X.foo'
x.bar  # => 'X.bar'

y = Y.new
y.test # => 'Y.test'
y.foo  # => 'Y.foo'
y.bar  # => 'Y.bar'
```

In this example we have two existing classes `X` and `Y`. We define the methods we would like to add to both `X` and `Y` in a module which I've called `Mixin`. We can then reopen both `X` and `Y` and include the module `Mixin` into them. Once that's done, both `X` and `Y` have their original methods plus the methods from `Mixin`.